# GRAILS Jquery Date Time Picker Plugin

Tags: grails, jquery-plugins

I am using the date time picker plugin, its all ok , but when i add this code in the file application.js

```
...
beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends 
...
```

the time picker (date picker ok) no longer appears

[plug in](https://grails.org/plugin/jquery-date-time-picker)

Answer (score 1):

A quick googling indicates there may be problems such as this with the jQuery UI Datepicker and the jQuery Timepicker addon. Those problems will probably be more likely with the use of the Grails plugin that includes an old version of the Timepicker addon.

I would suggest that you include and use the jQuery plugins directly, rather than through the Grails plugin that packages them.

Typically I would encourage you to update the Grails plugin to help out others as well, but I'm not sure these kind of plugins are worth the trouble really.